# Aggregating JSON items in a list in Python

Tags: python, json, aggregation

I would appreciate your help to aggregate dataset. I have a dataset something link below, and I want to aggregate ids if the other values are the same.

Current Data:

```
dataset= [
 {'title' : 'XYZ', 'Description' : 'XYZ Description', 'instance_id' : 'instance A', 'instance_name' : 'name A'},
 {'title' : 'XYZ', 'Description' : 'XYZ Description', 'instance_id' : 'instance B', 'instance_name' : 'name B'},
 {'title' : 'ABC', 'Description' : 'ABC Description', 'instance_id' : 'instance B', 'instance_name' : 'name B'},
 {'title' : 'ABC', 'Description' : 'ABC Description', 'instance_id' : 'instance C', 'instance_name' : 'name C'}
]
```

I want to get instance details for each title and description. Desired result should be as following:

```
dataset= [
{'title' : 'XYZ', 'Description' : 'XYZ Description', 'instance_info': {'instance_id' :['instance A', 'instance B'],'instance_name' : ['name A', 'name B']}},
{'title' : 'ABC', 'Description' : 'ABC Description', 'instance_info': {'instance_id' :['instance B', 'instance C'],'instance_name' : ['name B', 'name C']}}
]
```

I hope I could explain myself.

I tried to do it with aggregate item module but could not manage to work.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question has to do with JSON. Those are regular dictionaries in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using with this way;

```
dataset = [
    {'title': 'XYZ', 'Description': 'XYZ Description', 'instance_id': 'instance A', 'instance_name': 'name A'},
    {'title': 'XYZ', 'Description': 'XYZ Description', 'instance_id': 'instance B', 'instance_name': 'name B'},
    {'title': 'ABC', 'Description': 'ABC Description', 'instance_id': 'instance B', 'instance_name': 'name B'},
    {'title': 'ABC', 'Description': 'ABC Description', 'instance_id': 'instance C', 'instance_name': 'name C'}
]

new_dataset = {}
for row in dataset:
    if row['title'] not in new_dataset.keys():
        new_dataset[row['title']] = {
            'title': row['title'],
            'Description': row['Description'],
            'instance_id': [row['instance_id']],
            'instance_name': [row['instance_name']]
        }
    else:
        new_dataset[row['title']]['instance_id'].append(row['instance_id'])
        new_dataset[row['title']]['instance_name'].append(row['instance_name'])

print(list(new_dataset.values()))
```

output:

```
# output: 
# [{'Description': 'XYZ Description',
#   'instance_id': ['instance A', 'instance B'],
#   'instance_name': ['name A', 'name B'],
#   'title': 'XYZ'},
#  {'Description': 'ABC Description',
#   'instance_id': ['instance B', 'instance C'],
#   'instance_name': ['name B', 'name C'],
#   'title': 'ABC'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(dataset).groupby(['title', 'Description'], as_index=False).agg(list).to_dict(orient="records")
```

Output:

```
[{'title': 'ABC', 'Description': 'ABC Description', 'instance_id': ['instance B', 'instance C'], 'instance_name': ['name B', 'name C']},
 {'title': 'XYZ', 'Description': 'XYZ Description', 'instance_id': ['instance A', 'instance B'], 'instance_name': ['name A', 'name B']}]
```